# How do you specify the perimeter around an entity in corona?

Tags: coronasdk

I would like to see how to detect when touch event has entered the zone of an entity?  say within 20 pixels of its image border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to include a transparent border around the image.  The touch still triggers when it's on the transparent areas.  So, for example:

[image]

A touch on the transparent area around the ball will fire the touch event listener.  For a circle, you can even check the distance from the touch to the center of the circle, and ignore any that are "too far" from the center, giving a circular response zone.  If your image isn't circular, you may need more complex validation logic, but at least you'll get the touch event.

Answer (score 0):

Use math,

distance = math.sqrt((object2.x-object1.x)^2+(object2.y-object1.y)^2)

This will give you the distance between the two points, then you can check if thats in your area.

Not as simple as answer one, but useful.